# Are Übers and Key Wardens considered elite monsters?

Tags: diablo-iii

According to [diablowiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Elite#Superunique):

```
There are three types of elite monsters in Diablo III.
Superunique
[...] All quest monsters, including Diablo, are considered superunique. 
Rare
[...]
Champion
[...]
```

If I'm understanding this correctly it means bosses are affected by the "extra damage to elites"//"less damage from elites" affix some items have.

Are the Übers and Key Wardens, despite not being regular quest monsters, also elites and, thus affected by these affixes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are affected by these affixes. You can test that by getting a Witch Doctor with Gargantuan / Restless Giant.